# Type of function should be dynamic

Tags: angular, typescript

For each component I create a service which is more or less the same.

E.g.

```js
save(values: any): Observable<Register> {
  return this.httpClient.put<Register>(environment.apiBaseUrl + 'register', values);
}
```

Instead of that, I want a general service that I can use for all components. Somehow like this:

```js
save(values: any, path: string): Observable<Register> {
  return this.httpClient.put<Register>(environment.apiBaseUrl + path, values);
}
```

Then I could use `this.myService.save(myObject, 'my-path')`. But what about the type `Register`? This time I want the type to be `Login`.

Is there a way I could tell the function what type it should be?

Comment: See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make the `Register` type generic:

```
function save<T>(values: any, path: string): Observable<T> {
  return this.httpClient.put<T>(environment.apiBaseUrl + path, values);
}
```

this is then called with

```
const observable = save<Register>(values, 'register');
```

Comment: This is an **obvious, often-repeated duplicate**. Please vote to close as duplicate, pointing the OP (and others) at the already-existing helpful answers. Posting answers to duplicates it not useful.